# How to fix "TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method" error

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm attempting to differentiate between a discord message that is a number and one that is letters in a  Pick a Number game for a discord bot. I figured I could just use the startswith parameter to see if the message contained numbers, but it returns a "TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method" Whenever I try it. How can I fix this?

```py
if current_guess.startswith('1','2','3'):
            current_guess = int(current_guess)
            if best_id == "N/A":
                best_guess = current_guess
                best_id = current_id
            else:
                if abs(current_guess-number)<abs(best_guess-number):
                    best_guess = current_guess
                    best_id = current_id
                else:
                    return
```

since startswith only allows 3 parameters to search for, I just copied this code 3 times, each checking for three of the numbers 1-9.

I was expecting it to be able to detect whether or not a message consisted of numbers, but it just outputs an error I don't understand.

```py
 line 57, in PAN
    if current_guess.startswith('1','2','3'):
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check if the message is a number. You can use a try / except:

```
try:
    current_guess = int(current_guess)

except ValueError:
    # warn user about only being possible to send digits
```

Answer (score 0):

[`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) accepts only **one** string to search for; you could write your condition as:

```
if any(guess.startswith(n) for n in ('1', '2', '3'))):
    ....
```

if you just want to know if the first character of a string is a number you could also use [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) (although that would also match `'0'`):

```
if guess[0].isdigit():
    ...
```

depending on what you really want to look for you might also consider the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re):

```
if re.match('^[1-9]', guess)):
    ...
```

where `^` means the geginning of the string and `[1-9]` will match one of the characters in the range from `'1'` to `'9'`.

Comment: startswith accepts a tuple actually, they're just missing a set of paratheneses

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes, in a way... i got the impression the OP means that 3 strings can be looked for. if start `start` or `end` appear in the string, `startswith` will not return `True` (and again: i guess that is what the OP assumed).