# im trying to get the file to count and list all the 'input' and position in this file but it comes with error

Tags: python

```
from operator import index
fil = open('C:/læs_filer/test.txt')
laestfil = fil.read()
print ('indtast tekst her')
tekst = input()
antal = laestfil.count(tekst)
positioner = [antal for antal in range(len(laestfil)) if tekst.startswith(tekst, index)]
if (tekst in laestfil):
    print ('teksten findes og har placering', positioner, 'i filen. ' 'Det forekommer', antal, 'gange.')

else:
    print ('teksten findes ikke')
```

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

Comment: Looks like you are adding multiple strings in here--  if tekst.startswith(tekst, index)-- Have a look at this question. Might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332670/how-to-fix-typeerror-slice-indices-must-be-integers-or-none-or-have-an-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with the list comprehension. The list comprehension variable `antal` should be called `index` and you need to remove the import on top.

I did some other changes as well:

- you were reusing the `antal` variable.
- no need to find the search string if the count of occurrences in `laestfil` is zero
- f-strings are generally awesome. They make stuff a lot more readable.
- always use the `with open` pattern so you don't have any unclosed files.

```py
with open('path/to/file.txt') as infile:
    laestfil = infile.read()

search_string = input("indtast tekst her\n")
count = laestfil.count(search_string)
if count > 0:
    positioner = [index for index in range(len(laestfil)) if laestfil.startswith(search_string, index)]
    print (f"teksten findes og har placering {positioner} i filen.\nDet forekommer {count} gange.")
else:
    print("teksten findes ikke")
```